# Function that asymptotically reaches 1 with x between 0 and 1 a with slope factor

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function that asymptotically approaches 1 from the origin with x between 0 and 1. It needs to include a slope factor to increase or decrease the slope at a given x.

Comment: Maybe you can use this? (with some modifications) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: I tried out sigmoid functions but could not figure out how to have them reach one for x between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you need a smooth function, or can it be something like $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$; $f(x) = x$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $1$ otherwise ?

Comment: Smooth function ideally

Comment: Why is $f(x)=1$ not acceptable?

Comment: Mm $f(x) = 1$ does not asymptotically reach $1$, it is equal to $1$